# How to install the gnu cross compiler for ARM platform?

Tags: android, linux

I want to develop an app for my android smartphone. And so I need a cross compiler, that works on x86, but produces code for ARM Cortex processor.

Unfortunately, the linux package manager provides more than one variant of this compiler:

- gcc-arm-none-eabi
- gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
- gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
- gcc-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabi
- gcc-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf

Edit: made the question more precise.

Okay, I understood, that gnueabihf is suitable for processors with integrated float-point unit. But gnueabi? Will it only produce code for very old processors without fpu?

By the way: what about 32/64 bit? Which of these compilers can produce code for both, the ARM 32-bit and 64-bit architecture?

What does the multilib software do? What are it's advantages?

And why is the first package 'gcc-arm-none-eabi' not subdivided into variants with fpu or multilib support resp. without them?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Do you intend to run your ARM Cortex processor on some sort of distribution of linux? Which one? Did you try researching what each of those variants is? Hint: There is a [readme](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/287100883/readme.txt).

Comment: Thank you, good idea! But, as you know, on almost all modern smartphones, android is preinstalled as OS. Is it possible to replace it with linux? I think not.

Comment: *Is it possible to replace it with linux? I think not.* [Think again](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-smartphone-operating-systems/).

Comment: Will this manual also work for low-cost phones, like the Wiko Lenny?

Comment: From [here](https://www.gsmarena.com/wiko_lenny-6939.php): Dual-core 1.3 GHz Cortex-A7 and internal 4 GB, 512 MB RAM - I ran linux on a computer with 25 mhz and 4 MB RAM... kids these days. There's even an active(?) [MinixOnArm](https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:minixonarm) project (seems to use Cortex-A8 though).

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/)? It is a cross compile toolchain officially supported by Google.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! But sorry, I don't want to use a huge IDE, but a lightweight command line tool.